# JAXRS vs JAXWS(Heap utilization)

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf, jax-rs

We've written a java *CXF* service, which has both *JAXWS* and *JAXRS* endpoints. The client can request one of them to get a response.

**Some more details:**

We executed stress tests on this service. For that we set `Xmx` to `2GB` and used *JProfiler* to check heap utilization.
We detected a huge difference in heap utilization between JAXWS and JAXRS for similar requests.

Used heap space is ..

- 1.7 GB for JAXWS and
- 0.4 GB for JAXRS

**Question:**

Has anyone experienced this?
Is the difference based on the way these endpoints create output XML?

Comment: Are you using any WS-Policy, WS-Interoperability or WS-Authentication features that don't exist in the JAX-RS version?